# get the user input in awk

Tags: awk

Is there any way to read the user input through the awk programming?
I try writing a script to read a file which contained student's name and ID.
I have to get the name of the student from the user through the keyboard and return all student's results by using the awk.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can collect user input using the `getline` function. Make sure to set this in the `BEGIN` block. Here's the contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    printf "Enter the student's name: "
    getline name < "-"
}

$2 == name {
    print
}
```

Here's an example file with ID's, names, and results:

```
1 jonathan good
2 jane bad
3 steve evil
4 mike nice
```

Run like:

```
awk -f ./script.awk file.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the input file is formatted as:

```
name<tab>id
```

pairs and you want to print the line where the name in the file matches the user input, try this:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"; printf "Enter name: " }
NR == FNR { name = $0; next }
$1 == name
' - file
```

or with GNU awk you can use nextfile so you don't have to enter control-D after your input:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"; printf "Enter name: " }
NR == FNR { name = $0; nextfile }
$1 == name
' - file
```

Post some sample input and expected output if that's not what you're trying to do.

Comment: +1 nextfile... I can always learn things by reading your answer. even though all stuffs are in man page. You just gave nice explanation with practical examples.. make them easy to be remembered. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested with line

```
"awk 'BEGIN{printf "enter:";getline name<"/dev/tty"} {print $0} END{printf "[%s]", name}' < /etc/passwd"
```

and for me is better solution and more readeable.