# Using ARGV to get user input in awk script

Tags: unix, awk, argv

I know ARGV[i] can be used for storing user input. However, I want to use it in awk script and get the ARGV[i] to compare the field from another text file. If the ARGV[i] matches the field or the field contains ARGV[i] which is the user input, then I want to return the other fields of that line.
Let say I have a file, testing.txt

```
123123123:Walter White:1:2:3:4
123123124:Jesse Pinkman:1:3:4:1
```

This is my awk script, awkScript.awk

```
 #!/usr/bin/awk -f
    BEGIN{FS = ":"; print "ENTER A NAME: "}
    {
        for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
        {   
            if ($2 ~ /'ARGV[i]'/)
            {
                print "Member ID: " $1
            }
        }
    }
```

It just prints ENTER A NAME: when I execute the script file. It doesn't even get the input from the user.

Comment: `ARGV` cannot be used for interactive stuff. It the complete command line as the shell hands it over to the program, a.k.a. what you find under `/proc/PID/cmdline`. In your case it would look like `yourprogram 'Walter White' datafile`. 

If you want to get user input, you can have a look at [this question][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907238/get-the-user-input-in-awk

Comment: This would be far better suited to a pure *nix solution.

Answer (score 0):

From awk manual

```
ARGV is an array of command line arguments
```

That is the list of arguments passed while calling the awk sript.

you may want something like

```
    $echo 'ENTER A NAME'
    $read Name
    Jesse Pinkman
    $awk -v name="$Name" -F: '$2=name{print $1}' filename   
    123123123
    123123124
```

Here `-v` option creates a variable named `name` in awk script and assigns the value of `$Name` variable from shell to name

`$2=name{print $1}` the `$2=name` selects all lines where `$2` is `name` and prints the first column

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're thinking about wrt using ARGV[] but here's one way to do what you want in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; msg="ENTER A NAME:"; print msg} NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0; next} $0 in a{print a[$0]} {print msg}' file -
ENTER A NAME:
Jesse Pinkman
123123124:Jesse Pinkman:1:3:4:1
ENTER A NAME:
Walter White
123123123:Walter White:1:2:3:4
ENTER A NAME:
```